# How to create series of set in PHP

Tags: php

I need a function like range, where i will pass min and max values, it will return the set series.

For example,

```
createSeries(0, 50, 10, ' - '); // (min, max, interval, connector)
```

Should return me the following array

```
array('0 - 10', '10 - 20', '20 - 30', '30 - 40', '40 - 50');
```

What is the best i can accomplish this?

**EDIT:**
I have a function which gives me back the result. I have used range and for loop to get my result. Is there a better efficient way i can get it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Write a function. It took 4 lines of code)

Comment: What did you tried ?

Comment: I wish programming was as easy as posting a work order to Stack Overflow and getting ready-made functions but alas.

Comment: I have created my function using for loop. But poster here, whether there may be a better alternative efficient way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stylish functional code:

```
function createSeries($min, $max, $interval, $connector) {
    return array_map(
        function ($num) use ($interval, $connector) {
            return implode(' ', array($num, $connector, $num + $interval));
        },
        range($min, $max - $interval, $interval)
    );
}
```

However, the most efficient way seems to be:

```
function createSeries($min, $max, $interval, $connector) {
    $series = array();
    for ($i = $min; $i < $max; $i += $interval) {
        $tail = $i + $interval;
        $series[] = "$i $connector $tail";
    }
    return $series;
}
```

#### NOTE: PHP is very slow scripting language. You should not mind efficiency  extreamly.

Answer (score 1):

```
function createSeries($s, $e, $st, $d) {
    $result = array();
    for($i = $s; $i < $e; $i += $st)
       $result[] = $i . $d . ($i + $st);

    return $result;
}
```